# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium'. I double checked selenium was installed

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm learning python.
I created and activated a python virtual environment .Then i pip install selenium in the venv. It shows (`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium'`) when i run the program.

I checked if selenium is installed by pip list. Selenium is in the list. I also went to the my folder (`.\venv\selenium_projects\Lib\site-packages`) to check and the selenium folders and files are in there.  Did i do anything wrong? By the way after i install selenium in the global environment, the problem was fixed.

```py
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('http://www.baidu.com')
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "g:\Python\venv\selenium_projects\practice.py", line 1, in <module>
    from selenium import webdriver
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium'
```

Comment: Try `py -m pip list` and see if it's there.

Comment: How do you execute your script? You have to use the interpretor from the venv to find the module...

Comment: use the python like this `.\venv\selenium_projects\bin\python  practice.py`, it seems like you use different python.

Comment: @Jiu_Zou 管用 谢谢啦 问题解决了